# Springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException hibernate.SQLGrammarException MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, persistence

I'm breaking my head trying to find out what's wrong here. I'm working on a schema: It has a **Story entity (table: stories)** and I'm trying to add a column to this **stories.portofoliotype_id** which is a foreign key to **PortfolioType (table: portofoliotypes)**. I think I have the annotations right, I even logged MySQL queries, it gets the following query, which is correct. I'm trying to create a new story:
`insert into stories(backlog_id, description, iteration_id, name, parent_id,portfoliotype_id, state, storyPoints, storyValue, treeRank) values (11, null, null, 'debug story', null, null, 0, null, null, 0)`

but the hibernate fails with above mentioned exception. Here's the code :

**Story.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stories")
@Audited
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.NONE )
public class Story implements TimesheetLoggable, LabelContainer,     NamedObject, TaskContainer {
private int id;
private String name;
private PortfolioType portfoliotype;
private String description;
private Backlog backlog;
private StoryState state = StoryState.NOT_STARTED;
private int treeRank = 0;
private Story parent;
private Iteration iteration;
private List<Story> children = new ArrayList<Story>();
private Set<Label> labels = new HashSet<Label>();
private Set<User> responsibles = new HashSet<User>();
private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
private Set<StoryHourEntry> hourEntries = new HashSet<StoryHourEntry>();
private Set<StoryRank> storyRanks = new HashSet<StoryRank>();
private Set<StoryAccess> storyAccesses;
private Set<WhatsNextStoryEntry> whatsNextStoryEntries = new     HashSet<WhatsNextStoryEntry>();
private Integer storyPoints;
private Integer storyValue;
private Story fullInfoStory;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@XmlAttribute(name = "objectId")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
@XmlAttribute
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@ManyToOne(optional = true, targetEntity=PortfolioType.class)
@JoinColumn(name="portfoliotype_id")
public PortfolioType getPortfoliotype() {
    return portfoliotype;
}

public void setPortfoliotype(PortfolioType portfolio) {
    this.portfoliotype = portfolio;
}
```

**PortfolioType.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="portfoliotypes")
@Audited
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.NONE )
public class PortfolioType {
public PortfolioType() {}

private int id;
private String name;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@XmlAttribute(name = "objectId")
@Column(name="id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int portfoliotype_id) {
    this.id = portfoliotype_id;
}

@Column(nullable=false)
@XmlAttribute
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

And the stack trace :

```
12:30:09.681 [http-bio-9090-exec-5] ERROR o.a.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Exception occurred during processing request: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:130) ~[spring-orm-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:682) ~[spring-orm-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:564) ~[spring-orm-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755) ~[spring-tx-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724) ~[spring-tx-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475) ~[spring-tx-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270) ~[spring-tx-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.create(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at fi.hut.soberit.agilefant.web.StoryAction.create(StoryAction.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at fi.hut.soberit.agilefant.web.SettingsInterceptor.intercept(SettingsInterceptor.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at fi.hut.soberit.agilefant.web.SecurityInterceptor.intercept(SecurityInterceptor.java:198) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at fi.hut.soberit.agilefant.web.RefreshUserInterceptor.intercept(RefreshUserInterceptor.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) ~[xwork-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:546) ~[struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) [struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.14.2.jar:2.3.14.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at fi.hut.soberit.agilefant.security.RestrictActionPathFilter.doFilter(RestrictActionPathFilter.java:28) [classes/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:149) [spring-orm-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at fi.hut.soberit.agilefant.security.SetupUserFilter.doFilter(SetupUserFilter.java:43) [classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:95) [ehcache-web-2.0.4.jar:na]
        at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86) [ehcache-web-2.0.4.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.67]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.67]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3079) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3521) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:303) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:158) ~[hibernate-envers-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:62) ~[hibernate-envers-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:556) ~[spring-orm-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
        ... 130 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'portfoliotype_id' in 'field list'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar:na]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final.jar:4.2.18.Final]
        ... 148 common frames omitted
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance. Also, this test case works :
This test case works, i.e fetches rows from stories

```
@Test
public void testSearchByPortfolioType() {
    int searchfolio = 1;
    String name = "parity";
    PortfolioType portfolio = new PortfolioType();
    portfolio.setId(searchfolio);
    portfolio.setName(name);
    executeClassSql();
    List<Story> stories = storyDAO.searchByPortfolioType(portfolio);
    assertEquals(4, stories.size());
}
```

**StoryDAOImpl.java**

```
public List<Story> searchByPortfolioType(PortfolioType portfolio) {
    Criteria crit = this.createCriteria(Story.class);
    Criterion folioCrit = Restrictions.eq("portfoliotype.id",portfolio.getId());
    crit.add(folioCrit);
    crit.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
    crit.setMaxResults(SearchBusiness.MAX_RESULTS_PER_TYPE);
    return asList(crit);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to run the query in mysql directly ? It's showing that `portfoliotype_id` is not a column in `stories` table.

Comment: Do you have any errors configuring Hibernate?

Comment: I'm able to run the query directly in commandline. I am even able to query the table based on portfoliotype_id, but not able to insert a new row through hibernate.

Comment: @goKishore do you have any table  named 'field list' in your code?

Comment: no, I don't have any. I assume it is a generic error message, not sure what it means though.

Answer (score 18):

The error is basically saying that there isn't a field/column on `PortfolioType` called `portfoliotype_id` that it can find, because the field is actually called `id`.

This is a basic error because your ID column name doesn't match what you've specified in your `@JoinColumn` annotation.

Change the classes to the following and it should work.

```
public class Story implements TimesheetLoggable, LabelContainer, NamedObject, TaskContainer {
    /** other fields omitted for space **/

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, targetEntity=PortfolioType.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="portfolioTypeId")
    private PortfolioType portfoliotype;
}
```

Portfolio Type:

```
public class PortfolioType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute(name = "objectId")
    @Column(name="portfolioTypeId")
    private int portfolioTypeId;

    /** other fields omitted for space **/
}
```

You need to make sure that the `name` value in your `@Column` annotation, matches the `name` in your `@JoinColumn` annotation. Which is why always using `id` as your ID field name isn't a great idea.

Also, just a tip, putting these annotations on the setters, makes it much harder to read and work out what your relationships are. The usual convention is to to put these annotations on the field declarations.

Comment: Ok, should I do anything in the database at all? rename the columns?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a quite old question and it might help someone. If this exceptions prompts the causes can be diverse, in case of simpler DAO my advice would be simply to run the query directly to database and check what's wrong, for my case I had some old solution of materialized views refreshed via a function and a trigger and unfortunately my application didn't have refresh rights on that particular materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException` is thrown when database access is restricted to **Read-only mode** and you are trying to perform any DML query.

Comment: Was my case. Thanks