# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Hi I'm currently working with an app then I encountered the same problem here [Springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException hibernate.SQLGrammarException MySQLSyntaxErrorException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752560/springframework-dao-invaliddataaccessresourceusageexception-hibernate-sqlgrammar) I followed the instructions here but still get the error I don't know what to do anymore:

here is my model:
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable{

```
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "emp_id")
  private Long empId;

  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "middle_name")
  private String middleName;

  @Column(name = "last_name")
  private String lastName;

  @Column(name = "gender")
  private String gender;

  @Column(name = "address")
  private String address;

  @Column(name = "email")
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "birthday")
  private Date birthday;

  @Column(name = "contract")
  private Long contact;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy= "employee")
  @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
  private Work work;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employee")
  @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
  private Finance finance;
  //setters and getters
}
```

Work.java

```
  @Entity
  public class Work implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "work_id")
  private Long workId;

  @Column(name = "department")
  private String department;

  @Column(name = "position")
  private String position;

  @OneToOne
  @JsonBackReference
  @JsonIgnore
  private Employee employee;
  //setters and getters
}
```

Finance.java

```
  @Entity
  public class Finance implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "finance_id")
  private Long financeId;

  @Column(name = "assets")
  private int assets;

  @Column(name = "profit")
  private int profit;

  @Column(name = "loss")
  private int loss;

  @Column(name = "revenue")
  private int revenue;

  @Column(name = "cost")
  private int cost;

  @Column(name = "f_date")
  private Date fDate;

  @OneToOne
  @JsonBackReference
  @JsonIgnore
  private Employee employee;

  @JsonBackReference
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  @Column(name = "cust_id")
  private Long custId;

  @OneToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  private Customer customer;
  //setters and getters
}
```

here is the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
  long countByGender(String gender);
  List<Employee> findTop5ByOrderByFinance_RevenueDesc();
  List<Employee> findTop5ByOrderByFinance_ProfitDesc();
  @Query(
        value = "SELECT address, COUNT(*) AS address FROM employee GROUP BY address "
                + "ORDER BY address DESC LIMIT 5",
                nativeQuery=true)
  List<Employee> findByAddress();
}
```

here is the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'emp_id' not found.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1080) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2738) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
```

Comment: You write a query that returns an address and a count... How should hibernate map that to an `Employee`? You only get the `address` column and a counter, that is hardly mappable to a `Employee`.

Comment: So how should I go about it? Appreciate it if you could show me thanks

Comment: Dont try to return an `Employee`. You want to do something else, judging by your query.

Comment: I'll do something like List<?> findByAddress ?

Comment: It worked I changed Employee to ? then changed the alias address to tally

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it worked

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{
  long countByGender(String gender);
  List<Employee> findTop5ByOrderByFinance_RevenueDesc();
  List<Employee> findTop5ByOrderByFinance_ProfitDesc();
  @Query(
    value = "SELECT address, COUNT(*) AS tally FROM employee GROUP BY address "
            + "ORDER BY address DESC LIMIT 5",
            nativeQuery=true)
  List<?> findByAddress();
}
```

I changed Employee to "?" and changed the alias address to tally